# Why do python modules work in shell but not in the script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I am trying to make two programs. I want one to print the current weather of my city of residence and I want the other one to take data from an online account and return it. For those scripts I import the yweather module and the requests module. When I import them in the shell there are no problems but when I run the script it says "ImportError: No module named yweather". What am I doing wrong?

Shell:

```
>>> import requests
>>>
```

Script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tim/Desktop/login.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

This also happens for the yweather module

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same interpreter in both cases?

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same Python version while running script and in the prompt?

Comment: Show us the first line of the script.

Comment: @sphere The first line is exactly `import requests` as we can see in the error

Comment: OK, then no shebang is in the script itself like `#!/bin/python`. Then show us how exactly did you run the script in the shell.

Comment: One more observation. `$ python script.py` and `$ sudo python script.py`. The `sudo` can actually change the python to the system one.

Comment: you shouldn't ever need to use 'sudo' - it doesn't just use the system python, it gives the process full superuser priveleges, which means if the script writes a file, that file will be owned by root - and that is the simplest issue it causes. Using sudo is a stunningly bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

I have a same problem as you, but with package 'sklearn'.
With `scikit-learn` and `sklearn` installed, I run `import sklearn` in a .py file and it returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble'; 'sklearn' is not a package".

It turns out I made a funny mistake. I named the file 'sklearn.py'. So when I import `sklearn`, it probably just trys to import itself. I shouldn't have named that file 'sklearn.py'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the same version of Python? Try running the following in both the shell and in a script, compare the results.

```
import sys
sys.version
```

If they are not identical, you have two versions installed.

Comment: They both return the same. But after trying several things I found out that I can run the scripts without a problem when using terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a virtual environment while in script, and modules are not installed there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows , you probably have install Python twice . Did you install Python with Anaconda and install Python independently?

When you type Python in the command prompt do you get the same Python version that the one in your interpreter ?

If yes then go in your system panel and delete the program for the Python version running on command prompt .

Otherwise you can check what pythonpath you are using in the command prompt :

```
echo %PATH%
```

If different one way of fixing it in the Python interpreter :

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append('your certain directory')
```

Or you can also set a new path in the command prompt with :

```
 setx PATH "%PYTHONPATH%;C:\python27"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a similar situation as yours.
The module being imported is opensbli.
Here is the install guide: https://github.com/opensbli/opensbli/blob/version2.0/docs/installation_guide.pdf

The mistake I made is that I first cloned it to `/opt/` by `sudo` command, and move to the directory owned by my user. The problem is that since I clone it with `sudo` at first, the owner of the opensbli directory is `root` instead of my user, and this seems to be the reason I can't import it in script even with `sudo` command.

The fix is simple. Just remove the clone and clone it again without `sudo`.