# sys.path in virtualenv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, chalice

I am running `chalice local` inside virtual environment. I don't see the libraries installed in virtual environment. From inside `chalicelib/common.py`, I see the path (`sys.path`) to be set at:

```
['/home/sudip/myapp', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

But when I run python3.6 from virtual environment console, I see this:

```
(venv) myapp$ python3.6
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 29 2018, 03:28:50) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.path)
['', '/home/sudip/myapp/venv/lib/python36.zip', '/home/sudip/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6', '/home/sudip/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/home/sudip//myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>>>
```

Here the path is properly set. Why is this not happening in the former case? Hence I am getting lot of module import errors when I run my application, as for example: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jwt'`. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your virtualenv with the option `--system-site-packages` to get access to the system (and site) packages:

```
virtualenv -p python3 --system-site-packages myvenv
```